SharePoint List column conditional formatting
New to this still on the learning road.
Situation. I have a SharePoint list that contains the following columns:
Name, DOB, Location, Comments.
I need to use a conditional formatting rule that in the situation that the comments cell contains the text ".iso" the Name cell and the Location cell needs to change background into yellow. Is there a way to use a JSON script because with simple conditional formatting rules I cant create the condition if the column contains specific text.
Thanks in advance.

Add the following JSON to [Name] and [Location] columns
 
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(indexOf(toLowerCase([$Comments]), '.iso')>-1, '#FFFF00', '')"
  }
}


See Column Formatting and
Reference

Thank you for the quick reply. Unfortunately I cant make it work. I have changed the column name with the field number and also tried lower and capital letters but getting no reaction. The only time the Location column changes colour in yellow is when changing the ">-1" to "!=1" but with nil selection re the .iso being present.

@Ciprian, you have to use internal name your comments column in JSON. Check: How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?.

Hi. I was using the internal name with a small difference. I was using Field_3 instead of field_3. First letter seems to bee the issue. All working fine now. Thank you

Hi Ciprian, perhaps you could say thank you by accepting the answer Matiur has given.  (We love collecting points for answering questions)

Sorry didn’t know how this is working
